# Salesforce Data Event on a related object

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

We have a custom object called Reservation. This has a lookup field to Contact (called Customer__r.ID. If I configure a Salesforce Data Event to look for when a record is created or updated and a field Service Code is XYZ.

The configuration allows me to select the Reservation object and asks Who to Inject and shows me the related Customer__r.ID (Contact) object.

Will this allow me to listen to a change on Reservation and inject the related Contact?

[image]

Comment: Yes ! did you try it ?

Comment: I did and it didn't work. I'm working with Support. They are having me update the Connector. @zeljazouli have you used this before?

Comment: This was confirmed to work. I had to upgrade my Connector and clear my configurations first.

Comment: Perfect. You can mark your question as resolved.

Comment: @zeljazouli Dumb question...how do I do that? :-(